# How can I set a per-model connection based on the environment?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

This does not work:

```
// config/env/production.js
  models: { 
    mymodel: { 
      connection: 'some-connection'
    }
  }
```

but that is the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with:

```
//api/models/MyModel.js

  connection: sails.config.mymodel &&
              sails.config.mymodel.connection ? 
              sails.config.mymodel.connection :
              'fallback-connection';
```